# How to compute (manually) the MSE and $\theta$ with k-fold cross validation in a multiple linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, cross-validation, mse

Let's say we have data with predicting variables in a matrix $\textbf{X}$
and a vector of target value $\textbf{Y}$ and we want to find $\pmb{\theta}$ s.t.
$$
\arg\min_\theta\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n (X^{(i)} \theta - Y^{(i)})^2
$$
For this we want to use $k$-fold cross-validation to avoid
overfitting and have generalizable model. Let's say that $k = 4$. That
means for me that we fit 4 different model. The first model
fits the subset 1, 2 and 3 and, with the obtained
$\theta_1$ compute the Mean Squared Error (MSE) on
the subset 4. Then second model fits the subset 1,
2 and 4 and, with the obtained
$\theta_2$ compute the Mean Squared Error (MSE) on
the subset 3 (and so on for model 3 and 4)
let's implement it (in R):

```
library(ISLR)
library(broom)
library(tidyverse)

rowN = dim(Auto)[1]
subset1 = seq(0, (1*rowN/4), by = 1)
subset2 = seq((1*rowN/4)+1, (2*rowN/4), by = 1)
subset3 = seq((2*rowN/4)+1, (3*rowN/4), by = 1)
subset4 = seq((3*rowN/4)+1, (4*rowN/4), by = 1)


ComputeModel = function(subset1, subset2, subset3){
model=lm(mpg ~ weight + 
            origin + 
            horsepower + 
            year + 
            displacement + 
            acceleration, 
          data=Auto,
          subset=c(subset1, subset2, subset3))
return(model)
}

ComputeTheta = function(model){
  return(tibble(model1$coefficients))
}

ComputeMSE = function(model, subset){
  cat(c("MSE: ", round(mean((Auto$mpg-predict(model,Auto))[subset]^2), 3), "\n"))
}

model1 = ComputeModel(subset1, subset2, subset3)
theta1 = ComputeTheta(model1)
MSE1 = ComputeMSE(model1, subset4)

model2 = ComputeModel(subset1, subset2, subset4)
theta2 = ComputeTheta(model2)
MSE2 = ComputeMSE(model2, subset3)

model3 = ComputeModel(subset1, subset3, subset4)
theta3 = ComputeTheta(model3)
MSE3 = ComputeMSE(model3, subset2)

model4 = ComputeModel(subset2, subset3, subset4)
theta4 = ComputeTheta(model4)
MSE4 = ComputeMSE(model4, subset1)

MSE:  36.138 
MSE:  14.925 
MSE:  10.556 
MSE:  20.411
```

Here are my questions: At the end of the $k$-fold cross validation
procedure, how do we compute $\pmb{\theta}_{\text{cross-validation}}$ and
$\text{MSE}_{\text{cross-validation}}$? Is it simply the mean obtained
in the 4 models:
$$
\text{MSE}_{\text{cross-validation}} = 
\frac{\text{MSE}_{\text{model1}}+
\text{MSE}_{\text{model2}}+
\text{MSE}_{\text{model3}}+
\text{MSE}_{\text{model1}}}{4}
$$
$$
\pmb{\theta}_{\text{cross-validation}}=
\frac{\pmb{\theta}_{\text{model1}}+
\pmb{\theta}_{\text{model2}}+
\pmb{\theta}_{\text{model3}}+
\pmb{\theta}_{\text{model4}}
}{4}
$$

I read the part regarding this topic in [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/) by James, Hitten, Hastie and Tibshirani, but could not find the details answering the question (or did not understand it properly). Do you have a good read with details on the subject to recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculation of MSE cross-validation is typical, but calculating $\theta_{cv}$ as yours is not good in general. Recently, a [similar](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472214/cross-validation-averaging-across-estimates-vs-re-estimating-on-full-sample/472223#472223) question has been asked; see option (1) in the question. If $X^TX$ is not singular, the problem has only one minimum, and based on your data, you might not see any adverse effects of averaging out $\theta_k$. But still, I wouldn't advise it.

Cross-validation is typically used for two main purposes:

- Tune hyper-parameters (which you don't have)
- Estimate test error (which is MSE-cv you have, and it represents the MSE of future test data, i.e. you claim "we would have trained our model with all the training data, obtain a $\theta$, and calculate MSE on the test set and would have obtained a similar MSE"). This way, you can't claim a final model because you're using your data to report an estimated test error. You can't have your cake and eat it at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link @gunes. As I added in the question I read the part regarding this topic in "An Introduction to Statistical Learning by James, Hitten, Hastie and Tibshirani (http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/), but could not find the details answering the question (or did not understand it properly). Do you have a good read with details on the subject to recommend?

Comment: You may not see it explicitly in the books because for the parameters you’re doing an unusual thing. But, you should be seeing MSE cv in various books/posts/tutorials.

Comment: @ecjb is the answer ok for you or is there anything that is unclear?

Comment: Yes your linked answer gave me some hints. What really helped me understand the big picture of the problem though (I think) was the p. 242 of "The Elements of Statistical Learning" (https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf). As I understood it, you would fit a model and test it as follows: first you perform k-fold cross validation on a training set to select the optimal $\lambda$ (with the smallest error). Then you fit a model on the whole training set using the obtained optimal lambda. And then on the test set you compute the error of the model. Correct?

Comment: That is true, and follows from the first option I've listed above. But to add, if you don't want to test it using a separate data (when your dataset is small), you do CV and estimate the test error as you've done. This way, you can't use the same folds for HP tuning. You need nested folds.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @gunes. May I ask you what do you mean exactly by "you can't use the same folds for HP tuning. You need nested folds"?

Comment: Basically, you should use CV for either HP tuning or MSE estimation. If you want to do both, you need two-level CV. It's a long subject to discuss here, but here is an enlightening Q/A for it: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/nested-cross-validation-for-model-selection